# How to order a data frame by one descending and one ascending column?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame, which looks like that:

```
    P1  P2  P3  T1  T2  T3  I1  I2
1   2   3   5   52  43  61  6   "b"
2   6   4   3   72  NA  59  1   "a"
3   1   5   6   55  48  60  6   "f"
4   2   4   4   65  64  58  2   "b"
```

I want to sort it by I1 in descending order, and rows with the same value in I1 by I2 in ascending order, getting the rows in the order `1 3 4 2`. But the `order` function seems to only take one `decreasing` argument, which is then `TRUE` or `FALSE` for all ordering vectors at once. How do I get my sort correct?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I used this code to produce your desired output. Is this what you were after?

```
rum <- read.table(textConnection("P1  P2  P3  T1  T2  T3  I1  I2
2   3   5   52  43  61  6   b
6   4   3   72  NA  59  1   a
1   5   6   55  48  60  6   f
2   4   4   65  64  58  2   b"), header = TRUE)
rum$I2 <- as.character(rum$I2)
rum[order(rum$I1, rev(rum$I2), decreasing = TRUE), ]

  P1 P2 P3 T1 T2 T3 I1 I2
1  2  3  5 52 43 61  6  b
3  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  f
4  2  4  4 65 64 58  2  b
2  6  4  3 72 NA 59  1  a
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still a bit overwhelmed by everything R has, and did not know about the rev function. In the meantime, I had figured it out that if the second vector is numeric, I could order by max minus the vector, but the character vector was still a problem until you answered.

Comment: @rumtscho yes, that's how it's done in the help file of order which is where I got my inspiration from. ;)

Comment: Be sure to check out @dudusan's answer for data where this method would fail. The problem is that using rev() no longer keeps the rows all together, it simply flips the column upside down. It only worked in this case because the example was "nicely" arranged.

Comment: Please see below the answer by @dudusan, this answer is sadly not correct!

Answer (score 34):

I use `rank`:

```
rum <- read.table(textConnection("P1  P2  P3  T1  T2  T3  I1  I2
2   3   5   52  43  61  6   b
6   4   3   72  NA  59  1   a
1   5   6   55  48  60  6   f
2   4   4   65  64  58  2   b
1   5   6   55  48  60  6   c"), header = TRUE)

> rum[order(rum$I1, -rank(rum$I2), decreasing = TRUE), ]
  P1 P2 P3 T1 T2 T3 I1 I2
1  2  3  5 52 43 61  6  b
5  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  c
3  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  f
4  2  4  4 65 64 58  2  b
2  6  4  3 72 NA 59  1  a
```

Comment: Simple one without rank :  rum[order(rum$I1, -rum$I2, decreasing = TRUE), ]

Comment: Thanks, helped me ordeing my date column (whcih does not work with -)

Comment: @SomnathKadam the minus sign doesn't work in front of character vectors -c("a") returns an errors

Answer (score 26):

I'm afraid Roman Luštrik's answer is wrong. It works on this input by chance.
Consider for example its output on a very similar input (with an additional line similar to the original line 3 with "c" in the I2 column):

```
rum <- read.table(textConnection("P1  P2  P3  T1  T2  T3  I1  I2
2   3   5   52  43  61  6   b
6   4   3   72  NA  59  1   a
1   5   6   55  48  60  6   f
2   4   4   65  64  58  2   b
1   5   6   55  48  60  6   c"), header = TRUE)

rum$I2 <- as.character(rum$I2)
rum[order(rum$I1, rev(rum$I2), decreasing = TRUE), ]

  P1 P2 P3 T1 T2 T3 I1 I2
3  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  f
1  2  3  5 52 43 61  6  b
5  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  c
4  2  4  4 65 64 58  2  b
2  6  4  3 72 NA 59  1  a
```

This is not the desired result: the first three values of I2 are `f b c` instead of `b c f`, which would be expected since the secondary sort is I2 in ascending order.

To get the reverse order of I2, you want the large values to be small and vice versa. For numeric values multiplying by -1 will do it, but for characters its a bit more tricky. A general solution for characters/strings would be to go through factors, reverse the levels (to make large values small and small values large) and change the factor back to characters:

```
rum <- read.table(textConnection("P1  P2  P3  T1  T2  T3  I1  I2
2   3   5   52  43  61  6   b
6   4   3   72  NA  59  1   a
1   5   6   55  48  60  6   f
2   4   4   65  64  58  2   b
1   5   6   55  48  60  6   c"), header = TRUE)

f=factor(rum$I2)
levels(f) = rev(levels(f))
rum[order(rum$I1, as.character(f), decreasing = TRUE), ]

  P1 P2 P3 T1 T2 T3 I1 I2
1  2  3  5 52 43 61  6  b
5  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  c
3  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  f
4  2  4  4 65 64 58  2  b
2  6  4  3 72 NA 59  1  a
```

Comment: Check out Michele's answer, which seems to work and is more straightforward than my own.

Answer (score 7):

Let df be the data frame with 2 fields A and B
**Case 1: if your field A and B are numeric**
    `df[order(df[,1],df[,2]),]   - sorts fields A and B in ascending order` 
    `df[order(df[,1],-df[,2]),] - sorts fields A in ascending and B in descending order` 
 
    priority is given to A.
    
 
**Case 2: if field A or B is non numeric say factor or character**
    In our case if B is character and we want to sort in reverse order
    `df[order(df[,1],-as.numeric(as.factor(df[,2]))),] -> this sorts field A(numerical) in ascending and field B(character) in descending.`
priority is given to A.

`The idea is that you can apply -sign in order function ony on numericals. So for sorting character strings in descending order you have to coerce them to numericals.`

Answer (score 4):

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    #supposing you want to arrange column 'c' in descending order and 'd' in ascending order. name of data frame is df
    ## first doing descending
    df<-arrange(df,desc(c))
    ## then the ascending order of col 'd;
    df <-arrange(df,d)
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple one without rank :

```
rum[order(rum$I1, -rum$I2, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

Answer (score 3):

The default sort is stable, so we sort twice: First by the minor key, then by the major key

```
rum1 <- rum[order(rum$I2, decreasing = FALSE),]
rum2 <- rum1[order(rum1$I1, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rum[order(rum$T1, -rum$T2 ), ]
```

Comment: clarify answer with explanation

Comment: This does not always work. If T2 is a date vector it will give the error: Error in `-.Date`(rum$T2) : unary - is not defined for Date objects. This doesn't apply to the specific example provided but as general advice it's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
rum[order(rum$T1, rum$T2, decreasing=c(T,F)), ]
```

Comment: This would be very neat, but doesn't seem to work: compare the output of Roman Luštrik's  `rum[order(rum$I1, rev(rum$I2), decreasing = TRUE), ]` to your `rum[order(rum$I1, rum$I2, decreasing = c(TRUE, FALSE)), ]`. I don't think `decreasing` accepts a vector of values.

Comment: This is just wrong. Decreasing does not accept a vector, and this answer should not be relied on.

Comment: This will actually work (in at least R 3.4.0) since the default `method="auto"` will use `"radix"` for "short numeric vectors, integer vectors, logical vectors and factors", and `"decreasing"` can be a vector when `"radix"` is used. See the docs [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html)

Answer (score 0):

In @dudusan's example, you could also reverse the order of I1, and then sort ascending:

```
> rum <- read.table(textConnection("P1  P2  P3  T1  T2  T3  I1  I2
+   2   3   5   52  43  61  6   b
+   6   4   3   72  NA  59  1   a
+   1   5   6   55  48  60  6   f
+   2   4   4   65  64  58  2   b
+   1   5   6   55  48  60  6   c"), header = TRUE)
> f=factor(rum$I1)   
> levels(f) <- sort(levels(f), decreasing = TRUE)
> rum[order(as.character(f), rum$I2), ]
  P1 P2 P3 T1 T2 T3 I1 I2
1  2  3  5 52 43 61  6  b
5  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  c
3  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  f
4  2  4  4 65 64 58  2  b
2  6  4  3 72 NA 59  1  a
>
```

This seems a bit shorter, you don't reverse the order of I2 twice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the amazing package dplyr
there is a function called arrange.
you just set the data-frame and the columns you want to order considering the hierarchy you choose. the defualt is ascending order. but if you want in descreasing order you use the command desc.

rum <- read.table(textConnection("P1  P2  P3  T1  T2  T3  I1  I2
2   3   5   52  43  61  6   b
6   4   3   72  NA  59  1   a
1   5   6   55  48  60  6   f
2   4   4   65  64  58  2   b"), header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
arrange(rum,desc(I1),I2)

Comment: Please, show the output of your command in order to verify the correctness. Also, your answer relies on functions from an add-on package which has not been mentioned. Please, add the relevant `library()` call. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `xtfrm()` is the generic function to get a numeric vector that
sorts like the given input vector. Decreasing sorting can then be done by
sorting with the negated value of `xtfrm()`. (This is exactly how e.g.
dplyr’s `desc()` is implemented.)

For example, with the data in question:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "
P1  P2  P3  T1  T2  T3  I1  I2
2   3   5   52  43  61  6   b
6   4   3   72  NA  59  1   a
1   5   6   55  48  60  6   f
2   4   4   65  64  58  2   b
", header = TRUE)

df[order(-xtfrm(df$I1), df$I2), ]
#>   P1 P2 P3 T1 T2 T3 I1 I2
#> 1  2  3  5 52 43 61  6  b
#> 3  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  f
#> 4  2  4  4 65 64 58  2  b
#> 2  6  4  3 72 NA 59  1  a
```

This approach can be generalized into a base R function to sort
data frames by given columns, that also accepts a vector-valued `decreasing`
argument. From [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70785959/4550695) to
[this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70770756/4550695):

```r
sortdf <- function(x, by = colnames(x), decreasing = FALSE) {
  x[do.call(order, Map(sortproxy, x[by], decreasing)), , drop = FALSE]
}

sortproxy <- function(x, decreasing = FALSE) {
  as.integer((-1)^as.logical(decreasing)) * xtfrm(x)
}
```

And with the current example data, we (of course) get:

```r
sortdf(df, by = c("I1", "I2"), decreasing = c(TRUE, FALSE))
#>   P1 P2 P3 T1 T2 T3 I1 I2
#> 1  2  3  5 52 43 61  6  b
#> 3  1  5  6 55 48 60  6  f
#> 4  2  4  4 65 64 58  2  b
#> 2  6  4  3 72 NA 59  1  a
```