# A sensible function to sort dataframes

Tags: r

I am creating a function to sort data.frames (Why? Because of reasons). Some of the criteria:

- Works on data.frames
- Aimed at non-interactive use
- Uses base R only
- No dependency on any non-base package

The function looks like this now:

```
#' @title Sort a data.frame
#' @description Sort a data.frame based on one or more columns
#' @param x A data.frame class object
#' @param by A column in the data.frame. Defaults to NULL, which sorts by all columns.
#' @param decreasing A logical indicating the direction of sorting.
#' @return A data.frame.
#' 
sortdf <- function(x,by=NULL,decreasing=FALSE) {
  if(!is.data.frame(x)) stop("Input is not a data.frame.")

  if(is.null(by)) {
    ord <- do.call(order,x)
  } else {
    if(any(!by %in% colnames(x))) stop("One or more items in 'by' was not found.")
    if(length(by) == 1) ord <- order(x[ , by])
    if(length(by) > 1) ord <- do.call(order, x[ , by])
  }
  
  if(decreasing) ord <- rev(ord)
  return(x[ord, , drop=FALSE])
}
```

Examples

```
sortdf(iris)
sortdf(iris,"Petal.Length")
sortdf(iris,"Petal.Length",decreasing=TRUE)
sortdf(iris,c("Petal.Length","Sepal.Length"))
sortdf(iris,"Petal.Length",decreasing=TRUE)
```

What works so far

- Sort data.frame by one or more columns
- Adjust overall direction of sort

But, I need one more feature: The ability to set sorting direction for each column separately by passing a vector of directions for each column specified in **by**. For example;

`sortdf(iris,by=c("Sepal.Width","Petal.Width"),dir=c("up","down"))`

Any ideas/suggestions on how to implement this?

**Update**

Benchmark of answers below:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

m <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  "base 1u"=iris[order(iris$Petal.Length),],
  "Maël 1u"=sortdf(iris,"Petal.Length"),
  "Mikko 1u"=sortdf1(iris,"Petal.Length"),
  "arrange 1u"=dplyr::arrange(iris,Petal.Length),
  "base 1d"=iris[order(iris$Petal.Length,decreasing=TRUE),],
  "Maël 1d"=sortdf(iris,"Petal.Length",dir="down"),
  "Mikko 1d"=sortdf1(iris,"Petal.Length",decreasing=T),
  "arrange 1d"=dplyr::arrange(iris,-Petal.Length),
  "base 2d"=iris[order(iris$Petal.Length,iris$Sepal.Length,decreasing=TRUE),],
  "Maël 2d"=sortdf(iris,c("Petal.Length","Sepal.Length"),dir=c("down","down")),
  "Mikko 2d"=sortdf1(iris,c("Petal.Length","Sepal.Length"),decreasing=T),
  "arrange 2d"=dplyr::arrange(iris,-Petal.Length,-Sepal.Length),
  "base 1u1d"=iris[order(iris$Petal.Length,rev(iris$Sepal.Length)),],
  "Maël 1u1d"=sortdf(iris,c("Petal.Length","Sepal.Length"),dir=c("up","down")),
  "Mikko 1u1d"=sortdf1(iris,c("Petal.Length","Sepal.Length"),decreasing=c(T,F)),
  "arrange 1u1d"=dplyr::arrange(iris,Petal.Length,-Sepal.Length),
  times=1000
)
autoplot(m)+theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
R 4.1.0
dplyr 1.0.7
```

Comment: Does `dir` differ from `decreasing` only from the fact that it can be specified differently from different columns?

Comment: I'd use forloop.

Comment: @Maël I guess we can get rid of `decreasing` once `dir` works. If no columns are specified, then `dir` can default to `rep("up",ncol(x))`. Maybe `dir` is not be best name, it sounds a bit like directory.

Comment: You could take a look at the `gx.sort.df` function of the [rgr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgr/index.html). I like its syntax, with formulas: `gx.sort.df(dat, ~ colA + colB)`. And with a `-` instead of a `+` it sorts in descending order

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Interesting! Didn't know about this, but it uses formulas. One could parse it and do stuff to it, but I am not convinced that formulas work well for non-interactive use.

Comment: @rmf Are you "locked in" to the whole `function(x, by = character(), dir = character())` format?  It is possible to mimic [`dplyr::arrange()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html) in **`base`** R. So `sortdf(iris, c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width"), c("up", "down"))` would become `sortdf(iris, Sepal.Width, desc(Petal.Width))`, and so forth.

Comment: @Greg As I mentioned, this particular case is for non-interactive use (ie; use it inside other functions), so `desc()` is likely not going to work so well. But, for interactive use, `dplyr::arrange()` is probably the best option and I completely agree with you that it would be nice to have a base R equivalent that works similarly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt, using a function taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50116459/13460602), and assuming up is ascending, and down is descending. `dir` is set to "up" by default.

```r
sortdf <- function(x, by=NULL, dir=NULL) {
  if(!is.data.frame(x)) stop("Input is not a data.frame.")
  
  if(is.null(by) & is.null(dir)) {
    dir <- rep("up", ncol(x))
  } else if (is.null(dir)) {
    dir <- rep("up", length(by))
  }
  
  sort_asc = by[which(dir == "up")]
  sort_desc = by[which(dir == "down")]

  if(is.null(by)) {
    ord <- do.call(order,x)
  } else {
    if(any(!by %in% colnames(x))) stop("One or more items in 'by' was not found.")
    if(length(by) == 1) ord <- order(x[ , by])
    if(length(by) > 1) ord <- do.call(order, c(as.list(iris[sort_asc]), lapply(iris[sort_desc], 
                                                                               function(x) -xtfrm(x))))
  }
  
   if(length(dir) == 1 & all(dir == "down")) ord <- rev(ord)

  x[ord, , drop=FALSE]
}
```

You can then have multiple different directions to sort:

```r
sortdf(iris, by=c("Sepal.Width","Petal.Width"), dir=c("up","down")) |>
  head()

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
69           6.2         2.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
120          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virginica
63           6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
54           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
88           6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor
```

And other examples work as intended as well:

```
sortdf(iris)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
39          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa

sortdf(iris, c("Petal.Length","Sepal.Length"))
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
23          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
36          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2  setosa
15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
39          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa

sortdf(iris, "Petal.Length", "down")
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Interesting that it doesn't preserve order of row numbers. `all.equal(rownames(sortdf(iris,"Petal.Length")),rownames(dplyr::arrange(iris,Petal.Length)))`

Comment: By "it", I meant `dplyr::arrange()` and I never even noticed it before.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s another alternative that gets rid of all the branching logic by
ensuring you always find a proxy to sort by for each `by` column with
`xtfrm()`. For consistency with base, instead of using a “new” `dir`
argument, it might also be preferable to keep the `decreasing` argument, but
just allow it to be a vector that’s recycled to match the `by` length.

```r
sortdf <- function(x, by = colnames(x), decreasing = FALSE, ...) {
  if (!is.data.frame(x)) {
    stop("Input is not a data.frame.")
  }

  if (!all(by %in% colnames(x))) {
    stop("One or more items in 'by' was not found.")
  }
  
  # Recycle `decreasing` to ensure it matches `by`
  decreasing <- rep_len(as.logical(decreasing), length(by))
  
  # Find a sorting proxy for each `by` column, according to `decreasing`
  pxy <- Map(function(x, decr) (-1)^decr * xtfrm(x), x[by], decreasing)
  ord <- do.call(order, c(pxy, list(...)))
  
  x[ord, , drop = FALSE]
}
```

Thinking about this a bit more, I might even simplify this further and:

- Let `Map()` handle the recycling for `by` and `decreasing`.
- Let `[` handle throwing errors for incorrect indexing (and consequently also accept
  numeric indices for columns rather than just names).
- Not pass `...` (following the YAGNI principle).

This could then come down to two one-liner functions:

```r
sortdf <- function(x, by = colnames(x), decreasing = FALSE) {
  x[do.call(order, Map(sortproxy, x[by], decreasing)), , drop = FALSE]
}

sortproxy <- function(x, decreasing = FALSE) {
  as.integer((-1)^as.logical(decreasing)) * xtfrm(x)
}
```

Examples:

```r
sortdf(iris) |> head()
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
#> 9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 39          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
#> 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa

sortdf(iris, by = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")) |> head()
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
#> 9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 39          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
#> 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa

sortdf(iris, by = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), decreasing = TRUE) |> head()
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
#> 118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
#> 136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
#> 123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
#> 119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
#> 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica

sortdf(iris, by = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), decreasing = c(TRUE, FALSE)) |> head()
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
#> 119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
#> 123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
#> 136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
#> 118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
#> 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
```

Comment: Nice! I like the simplicity and the use of decreasing. I am surprised that this doesn't translate to faster execution time.

Comment: Yeah, to be honest I'm surprised to see there are any differences in performance at all. My first thought was that it might be because of the `xtfrm()` calls even on the non-decreasing cols, but now I'm not sure anymore. Regardless, I suspect the differences will be smoothed out quickly with larger data.

Comment: @rmf Oh I realized that my method is specifically slower for the case of sorting with only 1 column. In @Maël's answer that's special cased to avoid the `do.call()`, which is where the difference comes from.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating what exactly is `* xtfrm(x)` supposed to do in `(-1)^decr * xtfrm(x)`?

Comment: @tmfmnk Sure: `xtfrm(x)` gives a numeric vector that will sort in the same way as the original `x` would have. That let's you do a decreasing sort by taking a negative value. Of course for numeric inputs it doesn't matter, but it's required for factor/character inputs and let's you treat all inputs uniformly.

Comment: And the `(-1)^decr` is basically just a way to write `if (decr) -1 else 1` algebraically.

Comment: Perhaps a better explanation would be that we know how to sort numeric value in decreasing order: use the order you would get from sorting the negated values in ascending order. `xtfrm()` allows us to generalize to any input, including factor/character, by giving a way to turn them into numeric values for sorting purposes. `rank()` would do a similar thing, as is mentioned in `?xtfrm` documentation -- but `xtfrm()` is generic so allows custom methods for custom classes.